# Can I assign the address of shared memory to a pointer directly?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, shared-memory

I'm trying to create a shared memory for IPC. I want to put a structure with dynamic 2D array in it into the shared memory. Here is the structure.

```
/* struct with 2 2D arrays. */
struct _test {
    uint16_t **A;
    uint16_t **B;
} test;
```

I know that a double pointer is not actually a 2D array and I should use a *pointer to array* like `int (*ptr)[3]`, but the problem is that I can only get the size of the 2D array during runtime. So I have to declare the 2D array this way(at least what I know of).

Then I calculate the size of those two arrays in run time, say they both are 2x2 arrays, which takes 16 bytes(uint16_t is 2 byte). So I did this:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    size_t size = 16;  //size of two uint16_t 2D arrays.
    key_t key;
    key = ftok("dev/null", 1);
    int s_shm_id = shmget(key, size, IPC_CREAT|0600);  //get 16 bytes of shared memory.
    test *shm = (test*)shmat(s_shm_id,(const void*)0,0);  //attach it.

    //I want pointers in this struct to point at shared memory.
    test *ptr = malloc(sizeof(test));  

    //Array A starts at the beginning of shared memory.
    ptr -> A = (uint16_t **)shm;  //My main confusion is here. Is this right?
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
            ptr->A[i] =(uint16_t *)((uint16_t *)ptr->A + i*2);

    //Array B starts right after A.
    ptr -> B = ptr -> A[i-1] + 2;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
            ptr -> B[i] = (uint16_t *)((uint16_t *)ptr->B + i*2);
  }
```

I understand this is basically wrong, I got segfault, but how? What a pointer needs is an address to point at, since I have already created a space(using shmget), why can't I make a pointer to point at it? Thanks for any feed back in advance!

Comment: `test *ptr = malloc(sizeof (*test));` is what you want, since `sizeof(test)` is just like `sizeof(void *)` which is a pointer type, not an actual struct type

Comment: What is a `test`? Did you typedef the struct or did you forget to put the keyword in here?

Comment: @27Blend Please add relevant info to the question instead of commenting

Comment: @TheophileDano: Please excuse, but what you write is not correct. In the context of the question and assuming a C++ compiler `sizeof(test)` returned the size of the structure `struct test`. In C the code shown won't even compile.

Comment: Does the real also miss to include any headers?

Comment: So then please also do here.

Comment: `uint16_t **A;` does *not* define a pointer to a 2D-array. `A` is just a pointer to a pointer to `uint16_t`.

Comment: A pointer `p`  to an array of two `uint16_t` would be defined like this: `uint16_t (*p)[2]`.

Comment: @alk Thanks for your reply! I am aware of that, but as I said in the question, the row and col of the 2D array is unknown until runtime, so that seems the only way to declare a "2Darray-like" thing...

Comment: Ohyes, please excuse, I ignored what I read in your question. Yes, I did read it. :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after are "jagged" or "scattered" arrays, not "linear" arrays. A scattered 2D-array in fact is not one array, but 1+N arrays, with N being the dimension of the 2D-matrix you are after.

The code you show misses to allocated this 1 array inside "1+N".

Assuming you successfully allocated enough memory to hold two 2D arrays with dimension `N` of `uint16_t`, that is `2 * N*N * sizeof (uint16_t)` bytes, then the code to prepare the access to this memory might look like this (error checking left out for readability):

```
void * p = ... /* Allocate memory here; does not necessarily needs to be SHM. */

uint16_t ** A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  A[i] = ((uint16_t*) p) + i*N;
}

uint16_t ** B = malloc(N * sizeof *B);
for (size_t i = N; i < 2*N; ++i)
{
  B[i - N] = ((uint16_t*) p) + i*N;
}

/* Access A[0 .. N-1][0 .. N-1] and B[0 .. N-1][0 .. N-1] here ... */
```

Placing `A` and `B` inside a `struct` which in turn is allocated dynamically is left to you as an exercise.

Accessing the arrays' elements is done straight forward: `A[0][0]` accesses the 1st array's 1st row's 1st element.

For clarity the same code for `NxM` arrays

```
uint16_t ** A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  A[i] = ((uint16_t*) p) + i*M;
}

uint16_t ** B = malloc(N * sizeof *B);
for (size_t i = N; i < 2*N; ++i)
{
  B[i - N] = ((uint16_t*) p) + i*M;
}
```

Comment: is it `A[i] = ((uint16_t *) p) + i*N;` ?

Comment: @27Blend: Sure it is. Fixed.

Comment: :Worked like a charm.Thank you sir. But still don't understand why my code didn't work. The difference is that I directly point A to an existing address(created by `malloc` or `shmget` )instead of using the return value of `malloc`, but since these two addresses both are allocated, why does it matter that much?

Comment: @27Blend: Take a piece of paper and sketch graphically how my approach works. Then do the same for your approach. See the difference and become enlightened! :-)

Comment: Surely that should be `B[i - N]`. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @rici: Oh! Yes, yes, sure ... - fixed! Thank you! :}